# Markdown converters not working for me?

Tags: javascript, markdown, pagedown, showdown

I am using [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) to convert Markdown to HTML however it is not giving expected output.

HTML:

```
<p class="markdown">
# Highlight.js

---

Some more text here...
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.markdown').each(function(){
    var html = markdown.toHTML($(this).html());     
    console.log(html);
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

Output:

```
<pre><code>
# Highlight.js
---
Some more text here...
</code></pre>
```

So it simply surrounded provided Markdown text with `<pre><code>` instead of output like below:

```
<h1>Highlight.js</h1>
<hr>
<p>Some more text here...</p>
```

In fact I also tried other libraries such as showdown, pagedown, etc but output was always:

```
<pre><code>
# Highlight.js
---
Some more text here...
</code></pre>
```

Can anyone have an idea of what I am missing here ? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to construct a jsfiddle from this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works for me ... [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/uAufMHWaqJ7PNOVmeobj?p=preview)

What I've noticed though is that if the markdown is indented it does not parse correctly.

this works

```
<p class="markdown">
# Highlight.js

---

Some more text here...
</p>
```

indented doesn't

```
<p class="markdown">
    # Highlight.js

    ---

    Some more text here...
</p>
```

Comment: Does your "indented doesn't" mean *it does nothing*, or does it mean that you get the same (wrong) `<pre>` output as the OP? Indentation with 4 spaces *is* valid Markdown, and it *should* translate to `<pre>` (in this case at least).

Comment: oh cool, yes it wad indentation issue, I forgot when you indent it is is shown as it like code. Thanks

Comment: @Jongware you're correct, it does translate to <pre/><code/> with 4 spaces, did not know that :)